# SPA from S3 and Java backend in the same domain. ALB fixed response limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-alb

I would like to have S3 bucked stored Single Page Application and its backend in the same domain. Now I am using ALB Listeners configuration to serve a fixed response for my `index.html` (by path). The default rule poits to a Target Group hosting my Java backend. Thanks to multiple Content-Security-Policy entries in the index file I am very close to reach 1024 characters limit. Do you know any way to avoid that? My `index.html` looks more or less like this:

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en">
<head>
<base href="/">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/ https://www.google.com/recaptcha/">
<meta name="viewport" content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimal-ui'>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico'></head>
<body>
  <xxx-root>
  </xxx-root>
  <script src="https://xxx.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/runtime.js.gz" defer></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't follow your question sorry. What's an "SPA"? What's a CSP? Suggest you rewrite your question if you want people to be able to understand it and help you.

Comment: I have updated the question but I think that a person who knows the answer should know these acronyms.

Comment: Ah, makes more sense now. You could get a custom domain for your S3 bucket, that would reduce the length of that URL. Do you need it shorter so you can add more content?